# php Imagick some formats missing

Tags: php, windows, apache, imagemagick, imagick

I've installed Imagick to my uwamp server and ImageMagick. After server restart, I had the following phpinfo:
[image: phpinfo]

As you see, there is Imagick installed and plenty of supported formats. But some important formats missing (jpeg, png). I was curious about that, so I  tried to run some conversion. The folowing error appeard:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to load module `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_SVG_.dll'
```

Its's strange, because I checked that the module is in the path, so why it can't be loaded? Any ideas?

EDIT:
C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\modules\coders have the following content:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install libpng and libjpeg. Depending on how you installed ImageMagick & Imagick, it might be as simple as adding the shared/dynamic library, or linking to them.

Info on resource and delegates [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php), and source-code to delegates can also be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)

Comment: I think I have the libraries installed - image in edited question.